Is the notation $\Delta_{i=1}^n a_i = a_1 - a_2 - \cdots - a_n$ for "cumulative subtraction" a good idea?
I noticed that there wasn't (or at least couldn't find) a notation that was essentially the opposite of the Summation notation (∑). So, you know how there is the Pi notation (for cumulative multiplication) and the Sigma notation (for cumulative addition). I did a bit of thinking and searching, and eventually thought of an idea for cumulative subtraction. I chose the symbol for cumulative subtraction to be the capital Delta letter (Δ).
Essentially, it's just summation, but instead of the addition, it's just subtraction.
$$\Delta_{i=1}^n a_i = a_1 - a_2 - \cdots - a_n$$
I had also found out that you can translate Summation to this formula as well.

So, does this idea/formula exist yet, and if it doesn't, can it be practical in our real world?

The cumulative operations tend to be reserved for associative operations; $(a - b) - c$ and $a - (b - c)$ are not equal in general. As you note, your notation translates to $a_1 - \sum_{i=2}^n a_i$, which is not that much longer to write.

I wouldn't say it is practical, due to the fact that it is just a simple translation of the usual summation notation.

Thank you all for your answers on this topic, this has been in my head for a while and I wanted some more opinions on the idea.

Also, $\Delta$ is used for forward differences.  Certainly notation can be reused (even better when there is little overlap of usage), but it's not clear that your proposed notation is a strong candidate.  Also, what would you call it?  By analogy with sum -> summation, you would have difference -> differentiation, which term is thoroughly dominated by its usage in calculus (and analogous operations in other settings).

I upvoted this question because at least it shows independent thought. Theo Bandit and Eric Tower's comments should be merged into an answer. One could also add a section on cumulative division and how it's relationship to cumulative multiplication is similar to the relationship between cumulative addition and cumulative subtraction.
